# Conversion of numpy array to image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

The array is a two-dimensional array populated with zeros and ones. How can I convert this array to a grayscale image such that there is a dot representing one in the array and an empty space where there are zeros. A sample of the final image is attached below.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Please correct your image, it is not attached!

Comment: Have you tried using Matplotlib or OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code needs numpy and pil libraries, install them by `pip install numpy pillow`.

You can comment out line with resize if scaling of image is not needed.

If you need borders just set borders pixels to 1. I set it in my code for example (see line with comment `# borders`).

Result is saved to `img.png`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66246489#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, PIL.Image
a = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype = np.uint8)
a[1, 4] = 1; a[2, 5] = 1; a[7, 6] = 1;
a[:, 0] = 1; a[:, -1] = 1; a[0, :] = 1; a[-1, :] = 1; # borders
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[a == 0] = 255
b[a == 1] = 0
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(b)
img = img.resize((100, 100), PIL.Image.NEAREST)
img.save('img.png')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how (using Pillow):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

image = Image.fromarray(array, mode="1")
```

`mode = "1"` means the image will be black and white, 1 bit pixels.

```
image = ImageOps.invert(image)
```

This is to invert the image so that pixels that are 1 are black and pixels that are 1 are white.

Comment: Thanks. The code works but the pixels need to be flipped which is very easy.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the answer